# Error in returning list for repr()

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a class 'mn_board()' that creates a m x n matrix as follows:

```
class mn_board(object):
    cell_char = 'O'
    def __init__(self, r, c):
        self.r = r
        self.c = c
    def __repr__(self):
        columns = [[self.cell_char]*self.c]
        rows = [columns*self.r]
        return rows
my_board = mn_board(4,5)
print my_board
```

However, it shows the following error:

```
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type list)
```

I am aware that the above should code displays only the list form and not the board form, that's not the problem I am facing as the list can easily be then converted into a matrix format.

Are lists not returnable in a repr() function? Any clarification?

Comment: try `return str(rows)`

Comment: `__repr__` has to return a string. That is what it is for. If you want to return the string representation of a list, then return `repr(rows)` or `str(rows)`.

Answer (score 0):

`Repr` is basically to return the value of type string in a printable representation. From your code it is returning of type `list` so got the error. Now try to convert using `str()` by `return str(rows)`

You can find more description at **https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr or **[https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.**repr**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__)

Change the code to :

```
class mn_board(object):
    cell_char = 'O'
    def __init__(self, r, c):
        self.r = r
        self.c = c
    def __repr__(self):
        columns = [[self.cell_char]*self.c]
        rows = [columns*self.r]
        return str(rows)
my_board = mn_board(4,5)
print my_board
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) (emphasis mine):

> object.__repr__(self)
>
> Called by the repr() built-in function and by
>   string conversions (reverse quotes) to compute the “official” string
>   representation of an object. If at all possible, this should look like
>   a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object
>   with the same value (given an appropriate environment). If this is not
>   possible, a string of the form `<...some useful description...>` should
>   be returned. **The return value must be a string object**. If a class
>   defines __repr__() but not __str__(), then __repr__() is also used
>   when an “informal” string representation of instances of that class is
>   required.